# Why can't I use Telerik's RadPanelBar with a standard collection of objects?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I am trying to use Telerik's RadPanelBar to display a list of objects. I would like the name to display when it is collapsed, and the object to display when expanded. For some reason this doesn't seem to work. Am I using this control incorrectly??

```
<telerik:RadPanelBar ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" />
```

The Control renders correctly, with the correct number of items, however I cannot expand any of the items. I would like this to render as something like:

```
<Item Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False" />
<Item Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="True">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
</Item>
<Item Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False" />
<Item Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the RadPanelBar needs to be bound to a collection within a collection. It doesn't work with a single object. A workaround I use is this:

```
<telerik:RadPanelBar ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
    <telerik:RadPanelBar.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ObnoxiousWorkaroundForTelerik}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadPanelBar.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadPanelBar>
```

In my ContactClass I added a collection just for this....

```
private ObservableCollection<AgencyContact> _forTelerik;
public ObservableCollection<AgencyContact> ObnoxiousWorkaroundForTelerik
{
    get
    { 
        if (_forTelerik == null)
        {
            _forTelerik = new ObservableCollection<AgencyContact>();
            _forTelerik.Add(this);
        }
        return _forTelerik;
    }
}
```

If someone knows of another workaround that doesn't require me to create a collection of my class within my class please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with this control in particular, but I know that in other WPF controls if you are trying to display something that expands and collapses you need to define a HierarchicalDataTemplate. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx or for a more step by step approach see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx.

Looking on the Telerik forum it looks like this post has an example of doing this:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/panelbar/radpanelbar-datatemplate.aspx

Comment: Using a HierachialDataTemplate results in the same behavior